# Show text on a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a radio button which says "no" and "yes". By default, nothing is selected.

So what I'm looking to do here is, if someone select no, nothing happens, but if someone select "Yes" It should print a text below saying hello world.

Can someone help?

```html
<input type="radio" value="no-charge">
No
<input type="radio" value="charge">
Yes
```

Comment: You need to give your radio values a name and value first.  If the radios are related, they need to share the same name.

Comment: You can add an on-click listener to the yes radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up event listeners for clicks on the radio buttons. When either is clicked, you need to check the value of the checked button. When it's "yes", set your message to "hello world", and blank when it's "no":

```js
var radioY = document.getElementById("radioY");
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
var radioQuery = document.getElementsByName("query");

function start() {
  radioQuery[0].addEventListener("click", checkClicked);
  radioQuery[1].addEventListener("click", checkClicked);
}
//
function checkClicked() {
  for (var x = 0; x < radioQuery.length; x++) {
    if (radioQuery[x].checked && radioQuery[x].value == "yes") {
      msg.innerHTML = "Hello World";
      return;
    } else {
      msg.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
}
//
window.load = start();
```

```html
<input name="query" value="no" type="radio"> No
<input name="query" value="yes" id="radioY" type="radio"> Yes
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Here's a jQuery solution you might prefer:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#radioY").click(function() {
    $("#msg").text("Hello World!");
  });
  $("#radioN").click(function() {
    $("#msg").text("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' id='radioN' name='query' value='no' /> No
<input type='radio' id='radioY' name='query' value='yes' /> Yes
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Any jQuery approach to do the same task?

Comment: Yes, and jQuery would be easier. I see Shidersz has provided a jQuery answer

Comment: In his answer, the text doesn't disappear when I click no and doesn't appear back when I click yes but instead keep printing again and again

Comment: I've added a jQuery solution you might prefer

Answer (score 1):

Just add an event listener for `click` to the related element:

## Javascript solution:

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="charge"]').addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML += "HELLO WORLD!<br>";
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="no-charge">
No
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="charge">
Yes
<p id="someId"></p>
```

## JQuery solution:

```js
$('input[value="charge"]').click(function()
{
    $("#someId").html($("#someId").html() + "HELLO WORLD!<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="no-charge">
No
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="charge">
Yes
<p id="someId"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Way

```js
  let radio_1 = document.getElementById("radio_1")
  radio_1.addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("hello world")
  })
```

```html
  <input type="radio" value="no-charge" id="radio_1">
  <input type="radio" value="charge" id="radio_2">
```

2.Way

```js
    function myAlert(){
      alert("hello world")
    }
```

```html
  <input type="radio" value="no-charge" onclick=myAlert()>
  <input type="radio" value="charge" id="radio_2">
```

3.Way

```js
    $("#radio_1").click(function(){
      alert("hello world")
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="no-charge" id=radio_1>
  <input type="radio" value="charge" id="radio_2">
```

Comment: You can also do with onclick instead. The choice is yours.

Comment: inline bindings are generally frowned upon in modern javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener like so:

```js
document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", () => console.log("Hello world!"));
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="no-charge"> No
  <input type="radio" value="charge" id="yes"> Yes
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onChange(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("hello-world");
  console.log(event.target.value);
  if(event.target.value === "yes"){
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else { 
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group" value="no" onchange="onChange(event);">
No
<input type="radio" name="group" value="yes" onchange="onChange(event);">
Yes
<div id="hello-world" style="display:none">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="query" value="yes" id="radioY" type="checkbox"> Yes
<div id="msg"></div>

<script>
    var radioY = document.getElementById("radioY");
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
var radioQuery = document.getElementsByName("query");

function start() {
  radioQuery[0].addEventListener("click", checkClicked);
  radioQuery[1].addEventListener("click", checkClicked);
}
//
function checkClicked() {
  for (var x = 0; x < radioQuery.length; x++) {
    if (radioQuery[x].checked && radioQuery[x].value == "yes") {
      msg.innerHTML = "Hello World";
      return;
    } else {
      msg.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
}
//
window.load = start();
</script>
```